# Is there a way to handle input hidden value in onSubmit?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, forms

I'm creating a todo app and I'm thinking of sending the id of the todo I want to delete using the post method to delete it. I'm currently using `<form action="localhost" method="delete">`, but I'd like to do something a little more complicated, so I'm trying to pass the id to the OnSubmit handler. is there a way to use the id in OnSubmit? Is there any way to use id in OnSubmit?

Implemented code

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import axios from "axios";

interface Todo {
    id: number,
    text: string,
}

const ShowContent = () => {
    const [todoes, setTodoes] = useState<Todo[]>([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get<Todo[]>("http://localhost:8888")
            .then(res => {
                setTodoes(res.data)
            })
            .catch(_ => alert("useeffect error"))
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Todo App</h1>
            {todoes.map(todo =>
                <div key={todo.id}>
                    <div>id: {todo.id}, text: {todo.text}</div>
                    <form action="localhost:8888" method="post">
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value={todo.id}></input>
                        <button>Delete</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            )}
            <div>
                <form action="localhost:8888" method="post">
                    <input type="text"></input>
                    <button>Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

What I want to do

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import axios from "axios";

interface Todo {
    id: number,
    text: string,
}

const ShowContent = () => {
    const [todoes, setTodoes] = useState<Todo[]>([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get<Todo[]>("http://localhost:8888")
            .then(res => {
                setTodoes(res.data)
            })
            .catch(_ => alert("useeffect error"))
    }, [])

    const handleOnSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        
        // I want to get the id here.
    }
    
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Todo App</h1>
            {todoes.map(todo =>
                <div key={todo.id}>
                    <div>id: {todo.id}, text: {todo.text}</div>
                    <form onSubmit={handleOnSubmit}>
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value={todo.id}></input>
                        <button>submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            )}

        </div>
    );
}

export default ShowContent;
```

Comment: Does it have to be a form submission? Can't you just send a delete request using ajax after clicking on the delete button?

Comment: I think you can do it that way. In this case, I wanted to use a form to send the id.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to get the `id` from your hidden `input` through the event using `e.target` either with `FormData` or `document.querySelector`, but there are Typsecript issues with this.

You already have access to the `todo` in the loop where you create the form, so my recommendation is that you create a function which already knows the `id`.

You can change your handler to a curried function like this:

```
const handleOnSubmit = (id: number) => (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(`submitted todo ${id}`);
}
```

And use it like this:

```
<form onSubmit={handleOnSubmit(todo.id)}>
```

Comment: Thank you. This method is what I was looking for. It solved a lot of problems I was having.